# Angular get values from object - undefined

Tags: angular

I’m trying to get values from backend object. The first demo it’s ok:
My first model is

```
export class Test {
  public StringValue: string | undefined;
  public BoolValue: boolean | undefined;
  public TestList: Array<User>;
}
```

and my angular service has this method

```
public async getUsers(descrizione: string): Promise<Array<Test>> {
    console.log(' descrizione ' + descrizione);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.api.post('utentifull/1', '1').subscribe(
        users => {
          console.log('[METODO getutente ', users);
          console.log('StringValue TEST' + users['helloMessage']);
          console.log('Cognome TEST' + users['items'][0]['Cognome']);
          resolve(users);
        },
        err => {
          return reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

So my html page can have values from component.
Now I ‘m trying to get values from an object with this model

```
export class Compositetype5 {
  public ListasitiResult: Array<Compositetype4>;
}
export class Compositetype4 {
  public StringValue: string | undefined;
  public BoolValue: boolean | undefined;
  public Esito: Esito;
  public Listautenti: Array<User>;
}
```

I can get an object with values from back end in my service but I can’t have values from my component. In consol.log I have ‘undefined’.

```
  public async getSiti(descrizione: string): Promise<Array<Compositetype5>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.api.post('utentifull3/3', '1').subscribe(
        sitiperoracle => {
          console.log('[Compositetype5 sitiperoracle] : ', sitiperoracle);
          console.log('sitiperoracle[1] : ', sitiperoracle[1]);
          resolve(sitiperoracle);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('METODO getutente]: errore nel fetch utenti', err);
          return reject(err);
        }
      );
    });  }
```

Some ideas?
Thanks in advance.

[undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6zXD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `sitiperoracle` is an object which contains `ListaSitiResult`  as an array property.
You should use `sitiperoracle.ListaSitiResult[1]` for expected data.